# When should I use WebForms to deliver the User Experience my users are looking for instead of muddled MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I've been using MVC to re-implement an application that I once built using WebForms.  What I've noticed is the follow:

1. MVC works really well for simple pages, pages that don't require large amounts of state to be maintained between requests.  If the page requires any sophistication, then the purity of page's adherence to MVC quickly becomes a leaky abstraction and creates a very tight coupling between the View implementation and the controller.  My understanding of MVC is that there is a single controller that should be able to handle multiple views of a given model with very clear and clean separations between the two.
2. Another point of friction I'm seeing is that MVC implies that the business rules be enforced through the design of the model(which I love).  However as I build my application I soon see that validation should live client-side as well(if for nothing other than the user experience of avoiding multiple posts).  To me this seems another adulteration of the design pattern in that I'm storing business logic not only in two places but two languages as well!

The issue I have is that while WebForms doesn't give me nearly the control over the UI rendering and markup that is afforded me in MVC, I'm torn as to having to write metric gobs of code in the view to recreate the WebForm version of my application as well as deliver a similar user experience.

**So when approaching UI design and implementing a solution, how should I think about solving the problem that differs from the classic WebForms approach?  Also what is the Mason-Dixon line(does it even exist) where I should simply use WebForms to deliver the User Experience my users are looking for as easily as possible without creating a muddled MVC'ish application?**

Comment: There's nothing wrong about having a View-Controller coupling, the View is there to serve the Controller.

Comment: I would use xVal for client side validation instead of the server side code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are right about MVC being only good for simple pages. If you are making real world applications, you are adding lots of custom code that Web Forms is already providing. To make MVC applications work as good as Web Forms apps, you are giving up the so-called benefits of MVC anyway and are piling on things that are supposedly bad in Web Forms. MVC is just another way to attract a different set of developers but really is not adding anything worthwhile to the development community.

Answer (score 9):

MVC can maintain state just like WebForms does.  You still have Session or in MVC TempData, if you really need it.

Saying you have to write metric gobs of state management is a little hyperbolic.  ViewState like implementations are actually very easy to create.  ViewState at its core is just serialized and encrypted state information into a `<input type='hidden'>` field.  With MVCs model binding concepts this is really easy to implement.

You should also consider that with MVC fancy javascript goodness also becomes a lot more accessible.  In fact it is so much easier to maintain complex javascript based wizards or similar pages on the client browser you may not even need to use Session or TempData.

All new MVC developers eventually run into the "state management wall" while learning.  MVC just takes a different approach and you need to adjust your WebForms mindset to cope.   Learning how to implement the [Post/Get/Redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern and effective use of javascript/ajax will really really help in that regard.

MVC just looks foreign and crazy to WebForms developers but once you get over some learning hurdles you'll really start flying and maintaining state like a champ.   :)

---

Where you implement validation is your choice and its not required.   MVC helps automate generating client side validation from metadata so there is very little duplication.  You should also consider that there is a big difference between validating a zip code and then actual business logic.